# Matplotlib - <Figure size 1440x1440 with 0 Axes> instead of images

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to display my predictions on my validation dataset of 254 images.

This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i])])
        plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(1).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+18])])
        plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(2).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+36])])
        plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(3).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+54])])
        plt.axis("off")

...

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(7).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+126])])
        plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(8).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+144])])
        plt.axis("off")

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
for images, _ in val_ds.skip(9).take(1):
    for i in range(18):
        ax = plt.subplot(6, 6, i + 1)
        plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
        plt.title(class_names[np.argmax(predictions[i+162])])
        plt.axis("off")
...
```

But it work until `for images, _ in val_ds.skip(13).take(1)`, then it print this:
`<Figure size 1440x1440 with 0 Axes>` instead of images.

I want to display all my images with predictions but in this way it show only the first 144 images. I'm confused.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Perhaps you could comment a block and see whether matplotlib refuses plotting one block further, then it can be a hint that you reached some upper limit - I could not find any documentation of such an upper limit though

Comment: I've already done. But that's not the problem because if I run only the block where there is ```val_ds.skip(8).take(1)``` I have the same.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce the behavious without having the actual code. If you say the error occurs even with a single block  ( val_ds.skip(8).take(1) ) then write the minimal code generating the error, if possible with explicit arrays, we cannot access your input file.

Comment: Even with a single block but from ```skip(8)``` onwards.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See [ask].